# How can I get a pixel from a tile?

Tags: c#, maptiler

If I have a real world coordinate and the x16 tile images from tileserver-gl how can i get the exact pixel for that coordinate?

I mean, if i have the lat and the lon i can get a tile image but then how can i get the exact pixel from the image?

My images are 256x256 in x16.

Thanks :)

I have tried to modify this code to get the pixel from coordinates but I didnt get it.

```
public static string GetTileForCoordinates(double lat, double lon) {

        int xtile = (int)Math.Floor((lon + 180) / 360 * (1 << 16));
        int ytile = (int)Math.Floor((1 - Math.Log(Math.Tan(ToRadians(lat)) + 1 / Math.Cos(ToRadians(lat))) / Math.PI) / 2 * (1 << 16));

        if (xtile < 0)
            xtile = 0;
        if (xtile >= (1 << 16))
            xtile = ((1 << 16) - 1);
        if (ytile < 0)
            ytile = 0;
        if (ytile >= (1 << 16))
            ytile = ((1 << 16) - 1);

        return $"{xtile}_{ytile}";
```

}

Comment: Are you trying to get a pixel within a tile (which is the impression I get from your question title) or a tile from a pixel coordinate. You might want to make it clearer thar your coordinate system is 0-65536. Consider using `1 << 16 - 1` (65535) instead; it makes more sense (to me) to work in 16 bits rather than 17. Consider something like `const short MaxValue = (short) ((1 << 16) - 1);`

Comment: Im trying to get a pixel from coordinate. The process has to be: From coordinates get the tile, then in the tile get the pixel according to the coordinates